# Use images as background and apply to div parents with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, background

I'm trying to use img src as background-image of its parent div (with the same class) with jQuery way, but I need to apply the concrete url of its img child to every div without changing or adding extra classes or id, so that each div parent applies a corresponding different background-image.

My HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="class">
     <img src="url-image-1" />
</div>

<div class="class">
     <img src=“url-image-2” />
</div>

<div class="class">
     <img src="url-image-3" />
</div>
```

… and jQuery:

```
$('.class').css('background-image', 'url(' + $('.class img').attr('src') + ')');
$('.class img').remove();
```

**This code is grabbing the first element (url-image-1) every time**; it does not know I want to apply each img to its parent container.

Thanks in advance! (And sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$('.class').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + ')');
    $(this).find('img').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're selecting all the `.class img` elements. Calling `attr()` on that will only ever get you the first item found in the set.

To fix this, you can provide `css()` with a function that you can use to find the `img` related to the current `.class` element. Try this:

```
$('.class').css('background-image', function() {
  return 'url(' + $(this).find('img').prop('src') + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `each` function .And select the children image with `children('img')`

```js
$('.class').each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).children('img').attr('src') + ')');
  console.log($(this).children('img').attr('src'))
  $(this).children('img').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">
  <img src="url-image-1" />
</div>

<div class="class">
  <img src="url-image-2"/>
</div>

<div class="class">
  <img src="url-image-3" />
</div>
```